# Latex - Custom Reference to Custom Environment

Tags: latex, newenvironment

I want to do the following thing in Latex:

I have a custom environment like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\title{Item Table Test}

\newcounter{ItemDescriptionCnt}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\theItemDescriptionCnt}{Item \@arabic\c@ItemDescriptionCnt}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{ItemDescription}[5][]{\refstepcounter{ItemDescriptionCnt}\par\medskip
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X|>{\hsize=.6\hsize}X|>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Item No.}   & \textbf{Titel}   & \textbf{Type}          \\
        \theItemDescriptionCnt    &  #2   & Item                \\
        \hline          
        \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Description:}}     \\  
        \multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{#3}                               \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Note:} } & \textbf{Status:}    \\
        \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=.8\hsize}X|}{#4} & #5             \\
        \hline  
    \end{tabularx}
    \noindent \rmfamily}{\medskip}

\newcommand{\itemdescription}[5]{
    \begin{ItemDescription}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
        #5
    \end{ItemDescription}
}

\begin{document}

\itemdescription{This is the title}{This is the description.}{This is the note.}{pending}{\label{e}}

Here I reference \ref{e}.

\end{document}
```

This means I can then do

```latex
\itemdescription{This is the title}{This is the description.}{This is the note.}{pending}{\label{e}}

Here I reference \ref{e}.
```

Here you can see the generated file:
[image]

Which I already like! Now I would like to customize the reference.

I would like to do:

```latex
This is long reference: \longref{e}
```

Which should result in:

This is long reference: Item 1 - This is the title (pending)

I sadly can not figure this out -.-
I hope someone knows how to do that. Thanks in advance!

Bant

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the answer. I edited the question. I think the key is ```\csname \endcsname```.... I am still on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In case somebody want to do something similar I want to add how I got it doing what I want it to do.

The key is to use:

```latex
\expandafter\def\csname myitem\theItemDescriptionCnt\endcsname{#1}
```

inside

```latex
\newcommand{\itemdescription}[5]{
    \begin{ItemDescription}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
        #5
    \end{ItemDescription}
    \expandafter\def\csname myitem\theItemDescriptionCnt\endcsname{#1}
}
```

If I understand this correctly (And please correct me if I am wrong), the `\expandafter` lets the arguments first be "expanded" before the the `\def` is run. The `\csname [...] \endcsname` lets you define a constructed command within the enclosure. Then the `myitem\theItemDescriptionCnt` constructs a command, which in my example looks like this: `myitemItem 1`, which, when run, refers to the argument {#1}.

The following command `\longref` then does pretty much exactly the same.
It uses the input to get the reference number. It then puts it together to get the same command (inside the `\csname` enclosure), which was generated before.
The command then outputts the argument given before:

```latex
\newcommand{\longref}[1]{%
    \ref{#1} - \csname myitem\getrefnumber{#1}\endcsname
}
```

My complete example looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\title{tests}
\date{January 2024}

\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{ItemDescriptionCnt}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\theItemDescriptionCnt}{Item \@arabic\c@ItemDescriptionCnt}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{ItemDescription}[5][]{\refstepcounter{ItemDescriptionCnt}\par\medskip
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X|>{\hsize=.6\hsize}X|>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Item No.}   & \textbf{Titel}   & \textbf{Type}          \\
        \theItemDescriptionCnt    &  #2   & Item                \\
        \hline          
        \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Description:}}     \\  
        \multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{#3}                               \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Note:} } & \textbf{Status:}    \\
        \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=.8\hsize}X|}{#4} & #5             \\
        \hline  
    \end{tabularx}
    \noindent \rmfamily}{\medskip}

\newcommand{\itemdescription}[5]{
    \begin{ItemDescription}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
        #5
    \end{ItemDescription}

    \expandafter\def\csname myitem\theItemDescriptionCnt\endcsname{#1}
    \expandafter\def\csname mystate\theItemDescriptionCnt\endcsname{#4}
}

\newcommand{\longref}[1]{%
    \ref{#1} - \csname myitem\getrefnumber{#1}\endcsname\ (\csname mystate\getrefnumber{#1}\endcsname)
}

\begin{document}
  

\itemdescription{This is the title}{This is the description.}{This is the note.}{pending}{\label{e}}

Here I reference \ref{e}.

Here is the autoref \autoref{e}.

Here is the longref \longref{e}.


\end{document}
```

This generates:

[image]